# Server not reading jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I created an application using PHP, mysql, and jquery. It's working fine on my localhost,m however after uploading it to the server, everything works fine but jquery, I believe it's not reading it.

Using firebug, I get the following error when trying to read the .js file in the browser:

> Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected
>   token.

Here's how i include my scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/autoresize.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/customSelect.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.password.js"></script>
```

I did check my files and they exist in /js/ . What could be wrong?

**UPDATE**

It is working when I read :
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

But it's not working when reading from server?

Comment: Is your webpage running in the rootfolder where also the js folder resides?

Comment: try with live url of jquery from google site. but problem seems in ur calling/using of jquery

Comment: Yes it is: the webpage is located in /penpaper/ the javascript files are in /peppaper/js/

Comment: Is there any line# or file associated with the above error in firebug?

Comment: Which of your .js files gives the `Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token.` error?

Comment: Check the net tab of firebug to see if everything is loading to the browser

Comment: @hakre: the jquery file , when loading it with google api it works fine. but when reading from the file on the server, it's not working at all.

Comment: What character set are the files stored in?

Comment: @Orbling I'm using <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: @Mohamed Said: That is what you are telling the browser in the HTML, how are the JS files actually encoded, how are they being supplied to the browser?

Comment: @Mohamed Said: **which** .js file on your server is giving the error? It's not helpful to know that the files on some other server (like google) are okay if you want to find out about the error you have.

Comment: that file (js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js), the page is reading all the files but the jquery file.

Comment: Delete that file and upload the one from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js since you know it works from Google's server

Comment: @iolo Still not working though, I'm embedding the file from google api now and it's working fine, but I wish I can find a reason for why it's not reading the jquery file specificly.

Answer (score 2):

You are using relative path right now.

When you use relative path, all the requests will go to the path relative to your location.

For example, if you are on `http://www.mysite.com/products/catalog.php`, your browser will send the request to get the jQuery scripts from this location: `http://www.mysite.com/products/js/` which certainly does not exists.

Try using the absolute path instead. In fact make a habit of!

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/srcipt/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/srcipt/autoresize.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/srcipt/customSelect.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/srcipt/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/srcipt/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/srcipt/jquery.validate.password.js"></script>
```

Comment: the root file is http://ican-create.com/penpaper/index.php . when using the absolute path, it reads the file in http://ican-create.com/js

Comment: @Ruby: A main point in your answer is false. A relative link of `js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js` on `http://www.mysite.com/about.php` will resolve to `http://www.mysite.com/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js` but not (as you write) `http://www.mysite.com/about.php/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js`. And it's a misconception to think that absolute links are better than relative links or vice-versa.

Comment: @Mohamed. The linked page only loads four of the files from the list in your question

Comment: @Hakre: Agreed! It's 5 AM guess need some tea!

Comment: @iolo, and why is that? the files do exist on the server, what is the problem ?

Comment: @Mohamed: use this path: `/penpaper/js/your_script.js`

Comment: @Ruby, I did, however it reads all the files but the jquery file. It's freaking me.

Comment: Its because there's only 4 `<script>` tags in the HTML file. You need to add 2 more

Comment: @iolo, No there are 6 <script> tags included.

Comment: @Mohamed: This is the code I see in your page:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/autoresize.jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/customSelect.jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>`

As you can see, there are only 4 `script` tags and they are still using relative urls.

Answer (score 0):

Shoud be an HTTP GET request for these js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

Sounds like it does not exist on the location. If you have nice urls implemented or file does not exist then it would not work, try using full path.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xyz.com/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still not working, it's not a problem with the path I believe.